# Infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to evaluate those infinite series? How are they called?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2^k}
$$

I'm really sorry for asking, but I can't figure out how to google such stuff when I even don't know the names/categories.

Comment: "differentiated geometric series"

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) may help you compute the sums.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks a lot, that's all I need to know ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{x}{1-x}\rightarrow\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Now let $x=\frac{1}{2}$, hence we have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k({\frac{1}{2}})^{k}=\frac{0.5}{(1-0.5)^2}=2$

Now if we take the derivative, we will have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^{k-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\right)=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^{k}=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$
Now if you let $x=\frac{1}{2}$, then you have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}=\frac{0.5(1+0.5)}{(1-0.5)^3}=\frac{1.5}{0.25}=6$$

Comment: Thank you AMIR for explicitly solving the problem. The  strategy of iterated differentiation and replenishing of x's is worthwhile to memorize.